# Why won't bash run scripts with carriage-return characters?

Tags: bash

I noticed that bash will refuse to run a script if it contains carriage-return characters at the end of its lines. To observe this create a file `hello.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hello
```

Now give it execute permissions:

`chmod 700 hello.sh`

And run with: `./hello.sh`. It works perfectly!

Now try this:

```
unix2dos hello.sh
./hello.sh
```

I get:

```
bash: ./hello.sh: cannot execute: required file not found
```

Why can't it run the script?

Comment: if you put a space/tab at the end of the shebang line it will work.

Comment: That's _not_ due to Bash, though. If you want to see what the script does if interpreted by Bash, run it with `bash ./hello.sh`.

Comment: @αғsнιη, I'm not sure it will. You'd get the hashbang line `#!/bin/bash \r`, which would tell the kernel to run `/bin/bash` with the argument `\r`followed by the file name as another argument. The shell would take that `\r` as the file name to look for...

Comment: `printf '#!/bin/bash \r\necho foo \r\n' > hello.sh; chmod +x hello.sh; ./hello.sh 2>&1 |cat -A` gives `/bin/bash: ^M: No such file or directory$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carriage Return is, for better or for worse, a valid character in a filename. Rather than your shell attempting to execute `/bin/bash` it's actually trying to execute `/bin/bash^M`, where `^M` here represents the CR character. This file doesn't exist so your shell cannot find the stated interpreter to execute the script.

Comment: That's not due to Bash, actually, but the kernel that interprets the hashbang line. Bash just does some guesswork to try to give a more useful error message than the confusing "No such file or directory" when the script obviously exists. (Older versions give "bash: ./hello.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory", actually naming the missing file. I've no idea why the recent ones seem to have changed that.)